# Portando um código de Python 2 para Python 3: Scan ICMP com erros

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
import random
import socket
import time
import ipaddress
import struct

from threading import Thread


def checksum(source_string):
    sum = 0
    count_to = (len(source_string) / 2) * 2
    count = 0
    while count < count_to:
        this_val = ord(source_string[count + 1]) * 256 + ord(source_string[count])
        sum = sum + this_val
        sum = sum & 0xffffffff
        count = count + 2
    if count_to < len(source_string):
        sum = sum + ord(source_string[len(source_string) - 1])
        sum = sum & 0xffffffff
    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff)
    sum = sum + (sum >> 16)
    answer = ~sum
    answer = answer & 0xffff
    answer = answer >> 8 | (answer << 8 & 0xff00)
    return answer


def create_packet(id):
    header = struct.pack('bbHHh', 8, 0, 0, id, 1)
    data = 192 * 'Q'
    my_checksum = checksum(header + data)
    header = struct.pack('bbHHh', 8, 0, socket.htons(my_checksum), id, 1)
    return header + data


def ping(addr, timeout=1):
    try:
        my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_ICMP)
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
    packet_id = int((id(timeout) * random.random()) % 65535)
    packet = create_packet(packet_id)
    my_socket.connect((addr, 80))
    my_socket.sendall(packet)
    my_socket.close()


def rotate(addr, file_name, wait, responses):
    print ("Sending Packets", time.strftime("%X %x %Z"))
    for ip in addr:
        ping(str(ip))
        time.sleep(wait)
    print ("All packets sent", time.strftime("%X %x %Z"))

    print ("Waiting for all responses")
    time.sleep(2)

    # Stoping listen
    global SIGNAL
    SIGNAL = False
    ping('127.0.0.1')  # Final ping to trigger the false signal in listen

    print (len(responses), "hosts found!")
    print ("Writing File")
    hosts = []
    for response in sorted(responses):
        ip = struct.unpack('BBBB', response)
        ip = str(ip[0]) + "." + str(ip[1]) + "." + str(ip[2]) + "." + str(ip[3])
        hosts.append(ip)
    file = open(file_name, 'w')
    file.write(str(hosts))

    print ("Done", time.strftime("%X %x %Z"))


def listen(responses):
    global SIGNAL
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_ICMP)
    s.bind(('', 1))
    print ("Listening")
    while SIGNAL:
        packet = s.recv(1024)[:20][-8:-4]
        responses.append(packet)
    print ("Stop Listening")
    s.close()

SIGNAL = True

responses = []

ips = '200.131.0.0/20' # Internet network
wait = 0.002  # Adjust this based in your bandwidth (Faster link is Lower wait)
file_name = 'log1.txt'

ip_network = ipaddress.ip_network(unicode(ips), strict=False)

t_server = Thread(target=listen, args=[responses])
t_server.start()

t_ping = Thread(target=rotate, args=[ip_network, file_name, wait, responses])
t_ping.start()
```

O que eu tentei fazer:

```
ip_network = ipaddress.ip_network(unicode(ips), strict=False)
```

Mudei para:

```
ip_network = ipaddress.ip_network( ips, strict=False)
```

Pois estava obtendo: "NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined".

Depois obtive o erro: "TypeError: can't concat bytes to str" nessa linha:

```
my_checksum = checksum(header + data)
```

E então alterei:

```
data =  192 * 'Q'
```

Para:

```
data =  bytes(192 * 'Q').encode('utf8')
```

Agora obtenho o erro:

> "data =  bytes (192 * 'Q').encode('utf8') TypeError: string argument
>   without an encoding"

Alguém poderia me ajudar a portar o código para Python 3?

Comment: Eu não tenho experiência com o Python 3, mas que eu saiba para criar uma string de bytes basta colocar `b` antes das aspas. Experimente usar `data = 192 * b'Q'` e veja se resolve.

Comment: P.S. Pelo que eu entendi do *built-in* [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes), você precisa passar a codificação na própria função, e não chamar `encode` depois - `data = bytes(192 * 'Q', 'utf8')`. Ver também [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytearray). Mas minha sugestão anterior é mais simples.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, vou testar. Obrigado!

Comment: Usei data = bytes(192 * 'Q', 'utf8')   e agora o erro mudou:  "  this_val = ord(source_string[count + 1]) * 256 + ord(source_string[count])
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found"

Comment: @ stderr, obrigado. Se puder explicar, eu agradeço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined"

No Python 3, [`unicode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode) foi renomeado para [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str), e `str` para [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes). <sup>[Mais informações](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#text-versus-binary-data).</sup>

```
# Altere essa linha
ip_network = ipaddress.ip_network(unicode(ips), strict=False)

# Ela deve ficar desse jeito
ip_network = ipaddress.ip_network(ips, strict=False)
```

---

> TypeError: can't concat bytes to str

O erro acontece nessa função:

```
def create_packet(id):
    header = struct.pack('bbHHh', 8, 0, 0, id, 1)
    data = 192 * 'Q'
    my_checksum = checksum(header + data)
    # ....
```

A variável `header` recebe [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack) que retorna um objeto de [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes), `data` é uma [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str), no Python 3 não é possível concatenar `bytes` e *strings*, pois são dois tipos de dados diferentes. Para concatenar, coloque `b` como prefixo da `string`, assim ela vai ser reconhecida como uma [sequência de `bytes` literal](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

```
def create_packet(id):
    header = struct.pack('bbHHh', 8, 0, 0, id, 1)
    data = 192 * b'Q'
    my_checksum = checksum(header + data)
    # ....
```

---

> TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

No Python 3 a variável `source_string` é um objeto de [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes), que armazena uma sequência imutável de inteiros que estão num intervalo de *0* a *255*. Ao contrário de uma `string`, a indexação de um objeto de `bytes` retorna um inteiro. Veja um exemplo:

```
>>> foo = b'a'
>>> foo[0]
97
>>>
```

Neste caso a função [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) é redundante, não é necessário usá-la. Altere:

```
# De
this_val = ord(source_string[count + 1]) * 256 + ord(source_string[count]) 
# Para
this_val = source_string[count + 1]) * 256 + source_string[count]
```

Repita o processo onde estiver usando o `ord`.

---

Nessa linha:

```
ip = str(ip[0]) + "." + str(ip[1]) + "." + str(ip[2]) + "." + str(ip[3])
```

Você pode simplificá-la para:

```
ip = "{}.{}.{}.{}".format(ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3])
```

---

Ao salvar os resultados, o arquivo é aberto, mas não é fechado com o `close`:

```
file = open(file_name, 'w')
file.write(str(hosts))

file.close() # Faltou essa linha!
```

Como alternativa, você pode usar o [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with):

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(host for host in hosts))
```

O identificador do arquivo é fechado automaticamente após o uso.

---

Se quiser saber mais detalhes sobre como fazer a transição do código para o Python 3 e quais suas diferenças para o Python 2, veja o conteúdo do site abaixo:

> http://python3porting.com/preparing.html#preparing-for-python-3